# What if deque::size overflows in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, overflow

Consider the code snippet :

```
std::deque<int> myints;
size_type mySize = myints.size();
```

What if mySize overflows? Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: a deque's `size()` member cannot return a value larger than `max_size()`, which tops out at `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()`. I see no way you can ever expect an overflow to happen, as the deque cannot hold enough items to breach that limit to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you get to the situation you are describing an exception would have been thrown by the standard library.
E.g. `push_front` in the deque will throw in case you have reached a size which cannot by represented by `size_t`.

Comment: When can such a situation occur?

Comment: The size of the deque will increment as you push_front. 
When you push_front over the size of size_t it will throw.